# How to extract frequency from R table using vector of arguments

Tags: r

I have a table, for example:

```
tbl <- table(iris[, 1:3])
```

I can extract frequency from the table this way:

```
tbl[['4.6', '3.6', '1']]
```

How to do the same if my values stored as vector

```
vars <- c('4.6', '3.6', '1')
```

In fact `vars` is named vector and I need general way to extract from tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `vars` to matrix and use it to subset `tbl` :

```
tbl[t(vars)]
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
tbl[matrix(vars, ncol = length(vars))]
#[1] 1
```